# Need to Change the font color of a cell in MVC with respective values from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I need to change the colours of the values in a column from oracle DB in the MVC view based on the condition (if value in Column C = yellow then value in Column A = yellow;), actual from DB we are getting 4 columns in which we need to use 4th column for condition and should display rest 3 in UI 2nd column values color should reflect as per the condition. can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Share your relevant code so we can get proper idea and give you best solutions

Comment: Can you share your action and view?You can try to use if else statement in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly give assign the fourth column to the color tag in the same for loop you are using as below; let `EmpName`, `EmpHike`, `EmpSalary`, `Color`. The code below is how I changed the color:

```
<table>       
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>EmpHike</th>
            <th>EmpSalary</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (DBlayerList item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.EmpName</td>
                <td style="color:@item.Color;"> @item.EmpHike</td>
                <td>@item.EmpSalary</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```